# vagrantのLinuxでminikubeを動かしたい

Tags: linux, docker, ansible, kubernetes

vagrantのLinuxにminikubeを動かしたいですが、エラーとなり止まっています。
dockerやkubanetesを勉強したいためです。

手順１.
power-shellで、Cドライブ直下で以下のコマンドを実行

```
git clone https://github.com/takara9/vagrant-minikube
```

手順２．
power-shellで、以下のコマンドを実行

```
cd vagrant-minikube
```

手順３．
power-shellで、以下のコマンドを実行

```
vagrant up
```

#### エラーメッセージ

```
TASK [Add GlusterFS Repository] ************************************************
changed: [minikube]

TASK [Install GlusterFS] *******************************************************
changed: [minikube]

TASK [download] ****************************************************************
changed: [minikube]

TASK [download] ****************************************************************
changed: [minikube]

TASK [start Minikube temporary] ************************************************
fatal: [minikube]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/minikube", "start", "--vm-driver", "none"], "delta": "0:00:00.330972", 
"end": "2020-04-28 07:16:58.499318", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 78, "start": "2020-04-28 07:16:58.168346", "stderr": "X Sorry, Kubern
etes v1.18.0 requires conntrack to be installed in root's path", "stderr_lines": ["X Sorry, Kubernetes v1.18.0 requires conntrack to be install
ed in root's path"], "stdout": "* minikube v1.9.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 (vbox/amd64)\n* Using the none driver based on user configuration", "stdout_l
ines": ["* minikube v1.9.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 (vbox/amd64)", "* Using the none driver based on user configuration"]}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
minikube                   : ok=11   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

途中まではうまくいっている様子だが、以下のエラーメッセージが出力されてしまいます。
この作業を行うまでは、windowsの管理者アカウントが漢字名であったため、英語名の管理者権限を作りなおして実施しました。
dockerやminikubeを何度か入れなおしたりもしております。
また、windows10もhomeでしたが、dockerが正しく動かなかったため、proにしました。

同じような事象がないか調べましたが、なかなか見つからない状況です。
当方、インフラ構築は不慣れで、エラーを見ても見当がつかないです。
ご存知の方、詳しい方がいらっしゃったら、ご回答いただきたいです。

Comment: 今回の事象については[こちら](https://yukun.info/kubernetes-error-conntrack/)([issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7179))と同じかと思います。/ちなみに、参照されているVagrant boxが動作する、すなわちVirtualBoxが既にインストールされ動作している環境なら、[minikubeを直接Windows上で実行](https://kubernetes.io/ja/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/)する(`--vm-driver=virtualbox`)方が余計な面倒を抱えずに済むと思いますが、敢えてVagrantを用いたい、ということで良いでしょうか。

Comment: dockerやkubanetesを試すため、本に書かれていることを試したかったためです。仰る通り、同じ事象かもしれませんね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

最近のバージョンではnoneドライバで動作させる場合に `conntrack` というパッケージのインストールも必要になったようで、エラーメッセージはそれを表しています:

> X Sorry, Kubernetes v1.18.0 requires conntrack to be installed in root's path

- [none driver integration tests: k8s 1.18 needs conntrack installed #7179](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7179)

セットアップ時にこのパッケージもインストールするようにすれば([差分](https://github.com/takara9/vagrant-minikube/pull/1/files))動作しました。

Comment: yukihaneさん、試してみたところ、該当箇所の修正でうまくいきました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございます！