# minikubeでのgrafanaの起動方法

Tags: linux, docker, github, vagrant, kubernetes

メトリックス監視基盤であるgrafanaを起動させたいです。

[vagrantのLinuxでminikubeを動かしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/66063/vagrant%e3%81%aelinux%e3%81%a7minikube%e3%82%92%e5%8b%95%e3%81%8b%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)
にて、vagrant上でminikubeが実行できたので
以下の流れで、grafanaを起動させようと試みております。

ここから、
`http://Vagrant-Minikubeの仮想マシンのIP:30002/`
※IPは"172.16.10.10"で、30002は `kubectl get svc -n kube-system` で調べたポート番号

なんていうURLをたたいてみましたが、２．のような画面が表示されてしまいます。
ざっくりした情報しかだせておらず、申し訳ありません。
精通されている方がいらっしゃいましたら、不足している手順などがあれば、教えていただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**１．実行したコマンド**

```
vagrant@minikube:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takara9/vagrant-k8s/master/mon-influxdb/heapster-rbac.yaml
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/heapster created

vagrant@minikube:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takara9/vagrant-k8s/master/mon-influxdb/heapster.yaml
serviceaccount/heapster created
service/heapster created
error: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takara9/vagrant-k8s/master/mon-influxdb/heapster.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

vagrant@minikube:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takara9/vagrant-k8s/master/mon-influxdb/influxdb.yaml
service/monitoring-influxdb created
error: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takara9/vagrant-k8s/master/mon-influxdb/influxdb.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

vagrant@minikube:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takara9/vagrant-k8s/master/mon-influxdb/grafana.yaml
service/monitoring-grafana created
error: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/takara9/vagrant-k8s/master/mon-influxdb/grafana.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

vagrant@minikube:~$ kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
heapster              ClusterIP   10.106.18.235    <none>        80/TCP                   58s
kube-dns              ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   56m
metrics-server        ClusterIP   10.100.25.238    <none>        443/TCP                  35m
monitoring-grafana    NodePort    10.110.18.201    <none>        80:31500/TCP             18s
monitoring-influxdb   ClusterIP   10.102.218.128   <none>        8086/TCP                 37s

vagrant@minikube:~$ sudo minikube ip
10.0.2.15

vagrant@minikube:~$ kubectl proxy --address="0.0.0.0" -p 30002 --accept-hosts='^*$' -n kube-system
Starting to serve on [::]:30002
```

**２．`http://172.16.10.10:30002/` で表示した画面**

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps",
```

---

個人的な見解では、githubからheapsterなどをインストールする時点でerrorとなっているので、うまくいっていないと推測してます。
ただ、「kubectl get svc -n kube-system」を実行したとき、heapsterなどのIPがでているので、なんとも判断がつきにくいです。
この状態は何を意味しているのか？また、正しいインストール先も知りたいところです。

私の独力では、限界があると感じてます。ご存知の方、対応策を思いつく方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスいただきたいです。

Comment: 本の著者の高良です。 こちらの https://github.com/takara9/vagrant-minikube に、issueとして挙げて頂けると、回答させていただきます。

Comment: 高良様　コメントいただき、ありがとうございます。https://github.com/takara9/vagrant-minikube/issues/2　にて、記載しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ひとまずヒントはいただきましたが、解決してないため保留とします。